# What does it mean by .net SDK?

Tags: .net, sdk, rfid

What is **.net SDK** means?
i am interested in RFID scanner and i asked the seller that i wanted to make a custom application using their hardware, and they said that they could provide the .net SDK. I just wonder is it like the package that i can include in .net programming?
I am a beginner programmer, any link or explanation will be helpful.

Comment: What is the RFID company or the product ?

Comment: RFID is a product, example is an RFID tag used for electronic toll collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the .net SDK for RFID are C# library wrapping their C library that you need to include in your software.

You will normally have a example of use-case in the package and a documentation.

Comment: Is that means i can create any .net program i want as long as i have the hardware and i have the .net SDK?

Comment: Yes it is exact ! But you will be restricted to a specific hardware constructor. (RFID Tag and reader type)

Answer (score 0):

.NET SDK for RFID are the C# library which you can include in your project. It provides an API in which you can customise your rfid application with the available functions like read, read/write, kill etc.